# Why do I still need to add job.join() after I have used runBlocking in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning the Coroutines of kotlin.

The Image A can get the correct result.

I think I have used the code `runBlocking`, and main function will keep runing until it get final result, but Image B failed, why?

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the kotlin documentation about coroutines basics:

**Structured concurrency**

> There is still something to be desired for practical usage of
>   coroutines. When we use GlobalScope.launch, we create a top-level
>   coroutine. Even though it is light-weight, it still consumes some
>   memory resources while it runs. If we forget to keep a reference to
>   the newly launched coroutine it still runs. What if the code in the
>   coroutine hangs (for example, we erroneously delay for too long), what
>   if we launched too many coroutines and ran out of memory? Having to
>   manually keep references to all the launched coroutines and join them
>   is error-prone.
>
> There is a better solution. We can use structured concurrency in our
>   code. Instead of launching coroutines in the GlobalScope, just like we
>   usually do with threads (threads are always global), we can launch
>   coroutines in the specific scope of the operation we are performing.
>
> In our example, we have main function that is turned into a coroutine
>   using runBlocking coroutine builder. Every coroutine builder,
>   including runBlocking, adds an instance of CoroutineScope to the scope
>   of its code block. We can launch coroutines in this scope without
>   having to join them explicitly, because an outer coroutine
>   (runBlocking in our example) does not complete until all the
>   coroutines launched in its scope complete. Thus, we can make our
>   example simpler:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine in the scope of runBlocking
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego...

What you would say about this example why its not waiting for its child coroutine...
https://pastebin.com/RrHz9Fwc

Answer (score 4):

When you use `runBlocking`, your code between the `{ }` will run inside a `CoroutineScope`. If you run a child coroutine inside with `launch`, it will behave as you expected, because the parent coroutine has to wait for all its children before completing:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello, ")
}
```

However, when you use `GlobalScope.launch` to launch a new coroutine, it will not be tied to any parent, and therefore it won't be waited for, unless you add `job.join()`.

See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#children-of-a-coroutine):

> ## Children of a coroutine
>
> When a coroutine is launched in the CoroutineScope of another
>   coroutine, it inherits its context via CoroutineScope.coroutineContext
>   and the Job of the new coroutine becomes a child of the parent
>   coroutine's job. When the parent coroutine is cancelled, all its
>   children are recursively cancelled, too.
>
> However, when GlobalScope is used to launch a coroutine, there is no
>   parent for the job of the new coroutine. It is therefore not tied to
>   the scope it was launched from and operates independently.

Answer (score 3):

`runBlocking` will not return until all coroutines **in its own scope** have finished. Since your job is running on the `GlobalScope` instead it does not wait until it is finished. `job.join()` forces it to wait until the job (even from another scope) is done.

If you remove `GlobalScope.` it will launch on its internal scope and will work as you expect it should.

Comment: Thanks!  Can I always add `job.join()` even if it's in  its own scope ?

Comment: Yup, although `GlobalScope` is recommended to only be used for 'fire-and-forget' actions where you don't interact with the process after starting it, if you depend on the action happening it isn't a great fit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the point made by @huytc

To better understand the parent-child hierarchy you can use the `job.children.contains` like below

```
val customScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

fun main() = runBlocking {

val job = customScope.launch {
    println("processing")
    delay(1000)
    println("done processing")
}

println("Is custom scope child of run-blocking: ${this.coroutineContext.job.children.contains(job)}")



Output:
processing
Is custom scope child of run-blocking: false
```